# Linear Algebra - Determine if a linear transformation is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been faced with this question:

$T:\mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb R^3$ defined by $T(X) = AX$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&2\\2&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

How do I tell if this linear transformation is one-to-one?

Comment: It is linear. If the matrix isn't singular (has an inverse) it is one-to-one.

Comment: The question in the title and the body are rather different. To check if $T$ is linear, you need to determine whether $T(X + Y) = T(X) + T(Y)$ for all $X, Y \in\mathbb{R}^3$, and whether $T(cX) = c T(X)$ for all scalars $c$.

Comment: @T.Bongers sorry about that, how do i tell if the transformation is one-to-one?

Comment: @Cheryl Do you know the definition of one-to-one?

Comment: @T.Bongers x = y, right?

Comment: A linear operator $A$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $X$ is one-to-one if and only if the range of $A$ is all of $X$. Help yourself. If you want, i will give you a proof.

Comment: @Cheryl Where $x$ and $y$ are what? The definition has a mention of what the operator is; Try reading the formal definition in your textbook.

Comment: you need to show that rows of this matrix are linearly independent and for onto show columns are linearly independent

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$T$ is injective (1-1) $\iff (AX=\vec0 \iff X= \vec0)$ $\iff T$ is surjective (onto) $ \iff \det{A} \neq 0 \iff A$ is invertible..

Not necessarily in that order, and all of this due to linearity.

If you prove this chain, you will see the things hidden in between, and many things will become easier and easier to prove, I think.