# Statements about the correlation between invertibility of an operator and the corresponding matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, operator-theory, solution-verification

> Let $A\in M_n$. Prove the following:
>
> $(a)\;T\in L\left(M_{n\times 1}\right),\;T(X)=AX$ is invertible $\iff\; A$ is invertible.
>
> $(b)\;S\in L\left(M_n\right),\;S(X)=AX$ is invertible $\iff\; A$ is invertible.

---

My attempt:

$(a)$

Since $T\in L\left(M_{n\times 1}\right)$, $X$ is a column matrix, i.e.
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$
If $A$ is regular, then $\operatorname{rank}{A}=n\;\implies\;$  all the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Let $c_j$ denote columns of $A$.

$$AX\in M_{n\times 1}\implies AX=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\left(x_j\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^nx_jc_j$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^nx_jc_j=0\implies x_j=0\;\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\implies T(X)=0\iff X=0_{n\times 1}$$
$$\implies  \dim Ker (T)=0\implies T\;\text{is a monomorphism}\iff T\;\text{is an isomorphism}$$
because $M_{n\times 1}\cong M_{n\times 1}$.

Opposite direction:

Let $\{B_1,\ldots,B_n\}$ be some basis for $M_{n\times 1}$.

Let $X\in M_{n\times 1}$ be arbitrary and $\alpha_j\in\mathbb F$. Then

$$X=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j B_j$$
$$T(X)=T\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j B_j\right)=A\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j B_j\right)$$
$\dim Ker(T)=0 \iff$ the corresponding homogeneous system $A\left(\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j B_j\right)=0$ has a unique trivial solution $\iff\;\det A\ne 0\;\land\;\alpha_i=0\forall\;j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Since the basis is preserved, $T$ must be an *isomorphism .*

---

I thought I could use *Binet-Cauchy* for $(b)$ as the main tool so as to prove the statement by contradiction in both directions at once:
$$\det(AX)=0\iff \det A\cdot\det X=0$$
$$\det A=0\implies\;S(X)=0\;\text{for an arbitrary}\; X\in M_n\implies\;\dim Ker(S)\geqslant 1$$

---

May I ask for advice on how to improve my proof for $(a)$ and how to start the proof for $(b)$ if *Binet-Cauchy* isn't the right choice? Thank you in advance!

---

**Update - notation explanation:**

$T$ and $S$ are linear operators;

$T\in L\left(M_{n\times 1}\right)\equiv T: M_{n\times 1}\to M_{n\times 1}$

Analogously,

$S\in L\left(M_n\right)\equiv S: M_n\to M_n$

$M_n\equiv M_{n\times n}$

$\cong$ means isomorphic, so both
$M_{n\times 1}$ and $M_n$ are isomorphic to themselves because the relation '$\cong$' is reflexive.

---

Extra update:

We haven't formally gone neither through the spectrum of a linear operator nor the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. My apology for not mentioning it.

Comment: This seems related to some parts of this problem: [Linear Algebra - Determine if a linear transformation is one-to-one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699459).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thank you for the thread. Weeks ago, since our last lecture, we discussed the chain of the statements mentioned by the user in the answer. I'm not sure how far I should go because the matrix representation of a linear operator is a separate unit in our script. However, everything is (at least) intuitively clear, the relation between the range of an operator and the rank of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: a) is obvious. b) is a consequence of your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595937/if-lambda-a-in-lm-n-lambda-at-at-show-sigma-left-lambda-a-right/3598846#3598846
There are 2 answers. In particular, I explained to you that it is related to the Kronecker product; all you have to do is work a little bit.

Comment: @loupblanc, thank you, but I took that question on my own. We are formally far behind in theory. This is a question the lecturer gave us, so I'm suposed to avoid things the professors haven't sent us.

Comment: @loupblanc, the problem is, how not to refer to your answer now when I learned in advance, but the spectrum of the allowed tools is narrow. It is a consequence of something that is yet to come in our lectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof plan. Let $A\in M_n(K)$.

a) $T:u\in K^n\mapsto Au$.

$T$ (or $A$) invertible iff $\{Au=0\implies u=0\}$.

b) $S:X\in M_{n,p}(K)\mapsto AX\in M_{n,p}(K)$.

$S$ invertible iff $\{AX=0\implies X=0\}$ iff $\{A(C_1,\cdots,C_p)=(AC_1,\cdots,AC_p)=0\implies C_1=\cdots=C_p=0\}$

iff $A$ invertible (use $p$ times a)).

Comment: Thank you for your time, patience and proof plan! I still feel guilty for not posting the constraints into the post. If the lecturers post further lectures online, both of the answers will be helpful as well as now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I add a note:

$S\in L\left(M_n\right)$, and any linear operator $\Lambda\in L(V)$ in general is $\color{red}{\text{invertible}}\iff\color{red}{\text{regular}}\iff\color{red}{\text{epimorphism}}\iff\color{red}{\operatorname{rank}A=n}\iff A$ is invertible